# iOS: Cases when isAccelerometerAvailable is false on device

Tags: ios, swift, core-motion

I could not found anything particular on this question.

Is there a case where this property returns false on a device? And also this question applies to these properties as well: `isGyroAvailable`, all the available properties for pedometer and other sensors covered in `CoreMotion`.

Comment: There must be such cases otherwise the API wouldn't be needed.

Comment: Yeah, but what are those reasons?

Comment: Older devices don't have those features. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices

Comment: I just encountered this problem and I have no clue...

Comment: Ok I found the reason. I didn't init the CMMotionManager...